# upload images and store urls on database with laravel

Tags: laravel, image, upload

I want to upload multiples images and store her URL into a database.

Here's my code:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('validated', ['id' => $product->id]) }}) }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" name="ID" value="{{ $product->id  }}">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Image" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Image</label>
        <img src="{{ $product->imageURL }}" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Valider les données</button> | <a href="#">Relancer le fournisseur</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and into my Controller function:

```
$imagePath = Storage::putFile('uploads/image/', $request->image, "imagename");
```

I have this error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with
>   message "Call to a member function hashName() on string"
>
> Stacktrace: 0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError in
>   C:\laragon\www\MyProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter.php:208

Comment: Your form is missing the `<input type="file" name="image" />` element. and add the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag `<form method="POST" action="{{ route('validated', ['id' => $product->id]) }}) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Also use `$request->file('image')` not `$request->image`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your form must has a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute if you want to upload image.

Based on [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#file-uploads) you can use something like this:

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store('image');
```

Comment: Call to a member function store() on array on this line $path

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel, you should be able to do the following:

```php
$imagePath = $request->file('image')->store('uploads/image');
```

Or if you would like to specify the filename, you can do:

```php
$imagePath = $request->file('image')->storeAs('uploads/image', 'myfilename.jpg');
```

**UPDATED**

I have noticed that in your HTML form you don't have a file upload input. If you don't have one, Laravel won't have a file to store.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your answer, I tried but i obtain this error: Call to a member function store() on null

Comment: Change your form tag to `<form method="POST" action="{{ route('validated', ['id' => $product->id]) }}) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 1):

Hi i think you need to use putFileAs method to customize the name for example:

```
//Manually specify a file name...
Storage::putFileAs('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'), 'photo.jpg');
```

This method accepts either a Illuminate\Http\File or Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile instance and will automatically stream the file to your desired location:

[source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#storing-files)

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your answer, i tried too but I was the same error

Comment: yes @george-hanson is right, you don't have a file upload input, you need it with the name of  ```image``` to make the request and the enctype="multipart/form-data" part too.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple images upload, you can try this **code**:

```
$images = $request->file('images');
foreach ($images as $key => $image) {

    if ($request->hasFile('images') && $request->file('images')[$key]->isValid()) {
        $urlPath = $request->images[$key]->store('public/images');

        $image = new Images();
        $image->path = $urlPath;
        $image->save();
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Invalid Image file found!');
    }
}
```

**Assuming** that you have to added the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form and `Request $request` in your function arguments and also `storage link` in your public directory.

I hope it would helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do this if you want to write a reusable code and use it differently

for example we have Post and Image model
in Image model add this code

```
public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
 public static function named($name,$type)
{
    $photo = new static;
    $photo->saveAs($name,$type);
    return $photo;
}
public function saveAs($name,$type)
{
    $this->path = sprintf("%s/%s/%s-%s",'baseDir',$type,time(), $name);
    $this->name = sprintf("%s-%s", time(), $name);
    $this->type = $type;
}
public function moves(UploadedFile $file,$type)
{
    $file->move($this->baseDir.'/'.$type, $this->name);
    return $this;
}
```

and in a model that you want add an image for that like Post :

```
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }
     public function addImages(Image $image)
    {
        return $this->images()->save($image);
    }
```

and in controllers :

```
public function addImages(ImageRequest $request,$id)
 {
    $image = $this->makeImage($request->file('file'),$request->type);
    Post::where('id' ,'=', $id)->first()->addImage($image);
    return back();
 }

 protected function makeImage(UploadedFile $file,$type)
   {
     return Image::named($file->getClientOriginalName(),$type)->moves($file,$type);

   }
```